# How to display Blogspot posts on an HTML-based website?

Tags: html, blog, blogger

Hi
I've got a blogspot blog. I want to display my posts in my HTML-Based website. What should I do? I've already tried adding it as RSS but failed. I want everything to look natural. I don't want my visitors to notice that I'm writing these in blogspot.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't RSS work? That would be the easiest way to do it.

The other way would be to export your blog and import it to a hosted Wordpress or similar blog install. Read the Blogger documentation on how to export your blog. It should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Agreed this is the easiest way. Here's the link on how to export from blogger http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97416 and here is info on importing it into wordpress if you want to go that route http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use your blogspot blog with a custom domain name.
It could also be a subdomain. E.g. blog.example.com  where example.com is your website.
Here is the official site, which explains, what to do:
http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55373

Best wishes,

Adam

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this on a static HTML website you'll need to use something like an iFrame or some javascript to scrape the blogspot site for content. I'd go with the iFrame but you'll still see the blogspot header which gives it away you're hosting it there.

Also I believe it's against the [TOS](http://www.blogger.com/terms.g) to edit the content of your blog in a way that hides you're using their service when directly sending users there.

Comment: I let the "Powered by Blogger" remain there. I don't want my visitors to see my blog address directly

Comment: Gotcha, you might just want to do a full page iFrame wrapper. Just set the width and height of it to 100% with no border. It will mask all URL's and make deep linking for your visitors a pain, but it will let you hide that you're hosting it on blogger easily with a static setup.